# 3+ 3v and 1x 4.5v circuits with one or two batteries?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, batteries, circuit-design

This is my first post as I have been searching google for way to long for an answer.

I am building a Proton Pack for my grand kids.  Not trying to build something as a replica or anything just something for them to have fun with.

Currently I went to the dollar store and bought a few LED light kits that run off of 2x AA 1.5V batteries.

Also the gun portion runs off of 3x AAA 1.5v batteries.

I want to put about 3-4 LED kits in each pack and power the gun as well.

What I am trying to figure out is, "How do I power all of the different LED Kits and the Gun with the least amount of battery packs/batteries"?
[image: Proton Pack and Light kits]

Comment: Are all the LEDs on 3V ? then you need two All. packs. Otherwise use Lithium cells 3V with CR2 cell for LEDs and 4.5 Lithium for Proton pack (less common) for longer life. then switch both from common ground(-) but may need reverse diode for LEDs for switch off spike??

Comment: Yes all of the LED sets are 3v each.  I have a supply of the CR123 batteries I could use.

Comment: Good,  6V may be too much for Proton Pack so 1.3V drop with two diodes 1N4xxx or equiv. ... I meant CR123A , which is std what you prob have. are much more capacity than 2 alkaline cells and very stable voltage 3.00 It may be possible to mismatch load on 2 cells with tap off  1 cell for LEDs and 2 Cells for toy. but keep in mind it will age faster but smaller  so swap cells when lower cell needs replacement.

Comment: http://i4.photobucket.com/albums/y121/Bull_STR/Electronic/protonkitlights_zpsfjqzbf57.gif

Answer (score 1):

Just a concept for your consideration.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkExdv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Ok I will do that.  Thanks as this is much appreciated.  For the record, I have been playing with electronics since I was a child but nothing more than throwing a few lights on a circuit.  Your help has invigorated me.

Comment: Ok. So doing some research on the Rectifier Diodes (1N4001..1N4007), it says it doesn't matter which ones I use? 
So do all of them give a 0.7v drop?

Comment: Good for 1A steady yes roughly, then Vf rises with current, drops with no current